# How to out put HTML in Browser with Python

Tags: python, html

I've got a forms processing python script that just emails the input to me, then I just want to display a web page that say Message Sent with in Heading 1.  The email and forms processing part is working, but all I get is text displayed in the browser instead on the browser rendering the HTML.

```
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
```

I suspect its due to this line, any pls help?

this is what im trying to print

```
print "<html><head><title></title></head></html>"
```

I just tried running this test script

```
print
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'

print '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Python Sample CGI</TITLE></HEAD>'
print '<BODY>'
print '<H1>This is a header</H1>'

print '<p>' #this is a comment
print 'See this is just like most other HTML'
print '<br>'
print '</BODY>'
print '</html>
```

this is what I see in the browser after running it

```
Content-type: text/html


<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Python Sample CGI</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>This is a header</H1>
<p>
See this is just like most other HTML
<br>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Could You create a small eMail and show us the source of it.

Comment: right now Im just isolating the part I dont understand see above the test script has no email sending just output HTML to browser, but all I get is text.  I've tried various web servers apache, IIS, abyss web server, still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
print
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
```

Your HTTP header needs to be the first thing printed. You've got a blank line before it, which marks the *end* of the HTTP header. So the browser takes what you *intended* to be the HTTP header as the beginning of the response body. It doesn't see any HTTP header (except any provided by the Web server), certainly no `Content-type:` header.

Either the server or your browser is defaulting to a content type of `text/plain` in this case, so the browser does not try to interpret the HTML tags. *Et voila.*

TL;DR: Take out the first blank `print`.

Comment: I had just verified this was starting to type it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect the user to the page you'd like them to see:

```
print 'Location: /thanksforemail.html'
print
```

Comment: Ok that works, but I'd like to know why its rendering in text instead of HTML

Comment: Is the page rendering the HTML as text so you can see the tags directly in the browser window?

Comment: Are you sure that headers haven't already been sent somewhere else in the code before you output your `Content-type` header?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, firstly make sure that you have the correct she-bang notation at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

also, make sure that you import cgi, cgitb, and you have cgitb.enable(). (The cgitb stuff is not as important though)

Finally, make sure that your file is chmoded correctly. I usually make mine with permission 755. Hope that helps!

Comment: While useful for forms processing, those imports aren't needed for the simple test script in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `yourfile.py` file inside cgi-bin folder.
keep the `CGIHTTPServer.py` file outside cgi-bin folder.
Run `CGIHTTPServer.py` file after running your `yourfile.py` file.
You will get a port number may be 8000.
Then open your browser and type :
`localhost:8000/cgi-bin/yourfile.py`